# SQL Server - How to match exacty string with foriegn characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a column of type `nvarchar(max)`. It has data like this in it:

```
15583319|ግሩም
```

But when trying to query it for an exact match like this it is not returning anything

```
select * 
from clean..newkeymaster 
where fieldid = 4 
  and value like N'15583319|ግሩም'

select * 
from clean..newkeymaster 
where fieldid = 4 
  and value = '15583319|ግሩም'
```

How do I get a query to be able to match on this string when I am joining on two columns from two separate tables. The one holding the data like above is a `nvarchar(max)` like stated and the other `nvarchar(255)`. Something like this

```
from #temp t
inner join #temp2 e on e.tvalue = t.tvalue
```

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue. Is the table storing the data using the same encoding your client is using? Check the encoding on both sides and add them to the question.

Comment: What DBMS are you using? SQL Server? [Edit] the question and add the tag.

Comment: This is a Sql Server database and I am using enterprise manager to write the query on the database machine.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the collation is different between tempdb and your database.

```
SELECT name, collation_name 
FROM sys.databases
WHERE name IN ('tempdb', 'your_db_name')
```

You could use explicit [`COLLATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/collations?view=sql-server-ver15) providing the collation_name same as your db:

```
from #temp t
inner join #temp2 e on e.tvalue = t.tvalue COLLATE ...
```

Comment: TempDb and the one I am querying from both are set at SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: @ster The column on this specific table could have different collation defined.

Comment: Both the fields in the tables that my temp tables are built from have the same collation. SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS

Comment: Just playing around I tried collate Latin1_General_100_BIN2 and it worked to find the one row. Can you explain to me why this works? Will it mess up the matching for of my other rows that are not this language in my exampe?